# vuejs payload only emitting first element in an array

Tags: vue.js, dropzone

im using the dropzone plugin with vuejs and the response from dropzone is an array. The payload has an array of arguments, a response and the file object. Every time i call `@vdropzone-success="$emit('processFunction',$event)` it will correctly send the request to the right function but only the first element of the payload array is returned. Why? I have attached a screenshot of the vue debugger to help illustrate the problem. How can i access the payload in processFunction to get to array element 0 and 1?[image: picture of vue debugger where you can see the array payload. Only the first element is passed in $emit function]

to add more context. This is the function in the library that is emitting to my child component

```
    this.dropzone.on("success", function(file, response) {
  vm.$emit("vdropzone-success", file, response);
});
```

after this in my vue code i am emitting this result to my index component:

```
      <vue-dropzone
        id="dropzone"
        ref="myVueDropzone"
        @vdropzone-drop="$emit('loading')"
        @vdropzone-success="$emit('loaded',...$event)"
        :use-custom-slot="true"
        :options="dropzoneOptions"
      >
```

I am binding to the element on my index.vue here:

```
 <Upload  @loading="loading" @loaded="loaded" />
```

to then call the function loaded

```
loaded(e) {
  console.log(e);
  this.notLoading = true;
  this.isLoading = false;
},
```

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5527  this looks like A similar problem. Whenever i call $event it only returns 0 which is the file. I want it to return 1 which is the response from the serve (Object).

Comment: what happens when you use the spread operator with your single argument?

Comment: still only returns the first element of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok.. I feel like there should be a better way to do this, but... it looks like i can't pass the array variable through the vue tags from the library->child->parent directly. Instead I need to pull the array out in js in the child, and re-emit it in the js to the parent. the below solution worked.

library:

```
  this.dropzone.on("success", function(file, response) {
```

vm.$emit("vdropzone-success", file, response);
});

child (helper.vue):

```
          <!-- file upload -->
      <vue-dropzone
        id="dropzone"
        ref="myVueDropzone"
        @vdropzone-drop="$emit('loading')"
        @vdropzone-success="processdata"
        :use-custom-slot="true"
        :options="dropzoneOptions"
      >
```

and the js part of that

```
methods: {
processdata(...ev){
  this.$emit("loaded",ev);
},
```

and finally the parent (index.vue)

```
<Upload  @loading="loading" @loaded="loaded" />
```

and the js for that

```
loaded(...e) {
  this.storedValue = e;
```

not the most elegant solution, but it is working!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Child

```
@vdropzone-success="$emit('loaded')"
```

Parent

```
<Upload  @loading="loading" @loaded="loaded" />

loaded(payload) {
 this.storedValue = payload;
}
```

Comment: they are in separate files (child/parent relationship) so this won't work.